# Operate on several lists to create one list

Tags: list-manipulation

How do you put corresponding values from different lists together according to some operation?

E.g. I have three lists giving the velocity in the x, y and z direction respectively. I'd like create one list giving the 2-norm, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

I would be able to do it procedurally by using for example MapIndexed on one of the lists toghether with Part, I suppose. But I'd like to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I believe you will find [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5838577/618728) informative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general way to do this is using `MapThread`.  Using your norm example,

```
MapThread[Norm[{##}]&, {listX, listY, listZ}]
```

This particular example has easier solutions though:

```
Sqrt[ listX^2 + listY^2 + listZ^2 ]
```

Comment: I can't test in Mma at the moment, but I belive this is correct.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 4):

`Map` on the `Transposed` list seems to be faster than  `MapThread`

```
Map[Norm,Transpose@{listX, listY, listZ}]
```

but not nearly as fast as Szabolcs's second suggestion `Sqrt[listX^2+listY^2+ listZ^2]`.

Comment: Your method `Norm/@ Transpose@{X, Y, Z}` is faster than Szabolcs' firt one, and more general than his second one, since you can use e.g. `Norm[#,p]&` where `p` is a real number `>=1`, however in this case not much faster than the first one.

Comment: @Artes, good observation. Didn't think about other norms, but noticed that `Norm[#,2]&` and `Norm` gave roughly the same timings. More interestingly, `Total[{X,Y,Z}]` is about 10X faster than `Norm[#,1]&/@Transpose@{X,Y,Z}]` (roughly same improvement in the `Sqrt[X^2+Y^2+Z^2]` versus `Norm/@Transpose@{X,Y,Z}` comparison.)

Comment: `Norm[#,2]&` and `Norm` are equivalent, so it's not surprising they give the same timings, while `Norm[#,1]&/@Transpose@{X,Y,Z}]` and `Total[{X,Y,Z}]` are not, since you should do something like this `Total@Abs@{X, Y, Z}`, but I think even in this case the latter way would be faster, but haven't checked it.