# Point Belonging to a Disk in a Cartesian Coordinate System

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, regions, computational-geometry

The image below represents a human subject fixations while observing this abstract pattern for 3 seconds.

I would like to know how much time they spent looking at the actual disk. That is a red point within a Black Disk.

[image]

Each fixations (each sublist of "fixations" below is coded as such : `{{x,y}, Duration in ms}`.

```
 fixations=
 {{{20.3899, 14.8931}, 238}, {{27.0063, 18.8899},428}, 
  {{25.8113, 24.8679}, 377}, {{24.2579, 22.022},106}, 
  {{25.3208, 24.022}, 130}, {{21.739, 12.1792},175}, 
  {{29.2673, 8.88994}, 295}, {{30.3868, 17.6572},160}, 
  {{31.217, 22.6761}, 145}, {{22.9686, 20.6918},155}, 
  {{19.6321, 20.2704}, 145}}
```

Each Disk is coded as `{x, y, radius}`.

```
 Disks=
 {{22.8176, 19.9696, 0.974938}, {29.5314, 10.7197, 0.974938}, 
  {17.5112,19.7207, 0.974938}, {30.8997, 23.2454, 0.974938},
  {28.0588,6.09759, 0.974938}, {30.8524, 17.0661, 1.53205}, 
  {21.0393, 10.7137,1.53205}, {25.451, 25.1336, 1.53205}}
```

How could I :

- Count the number of fixations that are within a disk.
- Then how much actual time they spent there.

The only solution I thought about was to compute the `EuclideanDistance` of each fixation to each disk but I feel there is a smarter faster way to do this.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are overlapping disks possible? That would influence the algorithms (multiple hit counts).

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/clustering-of-space-time-data for some techniques closely related to this question.

Comment: @Yves Klett, no this case is impossible !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit: Version 1 using `Nearest`**

I think `Nearest` can be put to good use here anyway. This one uses the idea (inspired by @DanielLichtblau) that you can carry useful information in a `NearestFunction` that is not relevant for the actual distance by scaling those values with a small factor, finding the nearest points/vectors and the re-scaling the stowaways. While this is not exact, it can be very useful if you want to use "mixed" vectors and still get the performance gained by repeated use of a `NearestFunction` (here together with timing information).

Slight reformatting (scaling time with small factor):

```
fixations2 = Flatten[#]*{1, 1, 2^-20} & /@ fixations;
```

adding a 0 for compatibility...

```
Disks2 = Insert[#, 0, 3] & /@ Disks;
```

here we go (`NearestFunction` nf is called with additional arguments {n, radius}):

```
nf = Nearest[fixations2];

hits = Map[#*{1, 1, 2^20} &, 
   nf[#[[1 ;; 3]], {Infinity, #[[-1]]}] & /@ Disks2, {2}][[All, All, 
   3 ]]
```

> {{155}, {}, {}, {145}, {}, {160}, {}, {377, 130}}

```
Total /@ hits
```

> {155, 0, 0, 145, 0, 160, 0, 507}

This should scale pretty well with larger samples.

**Version 2 (straightforward)**

Another, very simple version with a bit of pattern mumbo-jumbo for versatile use with different input types (will become slow for large sample numbers):

```
fixations = {{{20.3899, 14.8931}, 238}, {{27.0063, 18.8899}, 
    428}, {{25.8113, 24.8679}, 377}, {{24.2579, 22.022}, 
    106}, {{25.3208, 24.022}, 130}, {{21.739, 12.1792}, 
    175}, {{29.2673, 8.88994}, 295}, {{30.3868, 17.6572}, 
    160}, {{31.217, 22.6761}, 145}, {{22.9686, 20.6918}, 
    155}, {{19.6321, 20.2704}, 145}};

Disks = {{22.8176, 19.9696, 0.974938}, {29.5314, 10.7197, 
    0.974938}, {17.5112, 19.7207, 0.974938}, {30.8997, 23.2454, 
    0.974938}, {28.0588, 6.09759, 0.974938}, {30.8524, 17.0661, 
    1.53205}, {21.0393, 10.7137, 1.53205}, {25.451, 25.1336, 1.53205}};

timeindisk[{{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, time_}, {u_?NumericQ, 
   v_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ}] := 
 If[Norm[{x, y} - {u, v}] <= r, time, 0]

timeindisk[#, Disks[[1]]] & /@ fixations
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0}

Threaded over fixes:

```
timeindisk[fixes_List, {u_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ}] := 
 timeindisk[#, {u, v, r}] & /@ fixes

timeindisk[fixations, Disks[[1]]]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0}

Threaded over fixes and disks:

```
timeindisk[fixes_List, disks_List] := timeindisk[fixes, #] & /@ disks

times = timeindisk[fixations, Disks]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 155, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>         0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 145,
>          0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>         160, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 377, 0, 
>         130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

```
(*    Time within disks: Total*)
Total /@ times
```

> {155, 0, 0, 145, 0, 160, 0, 507}

Answer (score 8):

This is neither ingenious nor pretty, but I guess it should be fast (not sure if faster or how much faster than Nearest based approaches, haven't tested), if you need to compute a lot and the compile time is not important. It stops checking when it has already found a fixation in a disk (so, assumed no-overlap)

```
isInDiskCmp = 
  Compile[{{pt, _Real, 1}, {disks, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{is = 0.}, 
    Do[If[Total[(i[[1 ;; 2]] - pt)^2] < i[[3]]^2, is = 1.; 
      Break[]], {i, disks}]; is], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True];
```

To see which fixations lied in a disk

```
fixationsInDisk=isInDiskCmp[fixations[[All, 1]], disks] == 1.//Thread
```

To count the total time spent in disks

```
Total[Pick[fixations[[All, 2]], fixationsInDisk]]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pointsInDisk = Function[{dsk}, 
Pick[fixations, UnitStep[Norm[#[[1]] - dsk[[;; 2]]] - dsk[[3]]] & /@ fixations, 0]];
```

Usage:

```
pointsInDisk/@Disks
```

gives

```
{{{{22.9686, 20.6918}, 155}}, {}, {}, {{{31.217, 22.6761},145}}, {}, 
  {{{30.3868, 17.6572}, 160}}, {}, {{{25.8113, 24.8679}, 377}, {{25.3208, 24.022}, 130}}}
```

Counts and durations in disks:

```
{Length@#, If[# == {}, 0, Total[Last /@ #]]} & /@ (pointsInDisk /@ Disks)
(* output: *)
{{1, 155}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 145}, {0, 0}, {1, 160}, {0, 0}, {2, 507}}
```

**Note:** For large lists replacing the argument of `UnitStep` inside `Pick` with

```
Sqrt[Inner[Times, #[[1]] - dsk[[;; 2]], #[[1]] - dsk[[;; 2]], Plus]] - dsk[[3]]
```

or

```
Sqrt[Total[Function[{y}, y^2] /@ (#[[1]] - dsk[[;; 2]])]] - dsk[[3]]
```

may improve timings (see, for example, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3121/125)).

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Outer` and `RegionMember`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
fixations = {{{20.3899, 14.8931}, 238}, {{27.0063, 18.8899}, 
   428}, {{25.8113, 24.8679}, 377}, {{24.2579, 22.022}, 
   106}, {{25.3208, 24.022}, 130}, {{21.739, 12.1792}, 
   175}, {{29.2673, 8.88994}, 295}, {{30.3868, 17.6572}, 
   160}, {{31.217, 22.6761}, 145}, {{22.9686, 20.6918}, 
   155}, {{19.6321, 20.2704}, 145}};

Disks = {{22.8176, 19.9696, 0.974938}, {29.5314, 10.7197, 
   0.974938}, {17.5112, 19.7207, 0.974938}, {30.8997, 23.2454, 
   0.974938}, {28.0588, 6.09759, 0.974938}, {30.8524, 17.0661, 
   1.53205}, {21.0393, 10.7137, 1.53205}, {25.451, 25.1336, 1.53205}};

disks = Disk[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ Disks (* to make these proper `Region`  entities*)
```

(* to find out which fixations are inside which `disks` *)

```
inside = Outer[RegionMember[#1, #2] &, disks, fixations[[All, 1]] , 1]

picks = Pick[fixations, #] & /@ inside
totals = picks[[All, All, -1]] // Map[Total]
counts = picks // Map[Length]

(res = Transpose[{disks, picks, counts, totals}]) //
 Grid[Prepend[#, {"Disks", "Point(s) in region", "Counts", 
     "Duration\n (ms)"}]
   , Alignment -> {Left, Center}
   , ItemSize -> {{20, 16, 5, 5}, 1.3}
   ] &
```

[image]

---

**Visualization**

```
SeedRandom[1];
GraphicsRow[{
  Graphics[{
    disks
    , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
    , Point@First@# & /@ fixations
    }
   , Frame -> True
   , PlotLabel -> "Input"
   ]
  ,
  Graphics[{
    MapThread[{Black, #1, RandomColor[]
       , AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@#2[[All, 1]]
       , Text[#4, #1[[1]]]} &
     , Transpose@res
     ] (* end of MapThread *)
    }
   , Frame -> True
   , PlotLabel -> "Output"
   ]
  }]
```

[image]